# integration with website with search

Tags: apex, api, integration

I have a task to integrate our SF org with this website: https://www.nsopw.gov/ , in which you can simply search somebody's name and find out of whether or not they are a sex offender. We would just want to pass the first and last name of some of our records in SF. Is this possible, and how is the best way to do it? Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per their [FAQ](https://www.nsopw.gov/en/FAQ):

> Does NSOPW offer a web service or an application programming interface (API) so searches can be done programmatically?

> No. The browser interface is the only way to search for sex offenders on NSOPW.

In theory, you could write some code to post the form and then parsing the resulting HTML, but it's a very manual process and may break if they change their DOM. What you're asking for is essentially not possible at this time.

Comment: Appreciate it- thank you! If I were to go the manual process, is there an example I can look at where such a thing is done? And would it be able to be done all with apex?

Comment: @MichaelM You can do this with Apex using the HttpRequest and HttpResponse classes to load the data, then the Dom.Document object to load and parse the HTML.